# Importing JS module to web browser script

Tags: javascript, html, module, nodes

I'm attempting to export content from a Google Spreadsheet to an internal script within an HTML page. I've successfully set up an API that connects the specific spreadsheet to a JS file and I'm able to console log cell content. Like so:

```
const { google } = require("googleapis");
const auth = require("./credentials-load");


async function run() {
  //create sheets client
  const sheets = google.sheets({ version: "v4", auth });
  //get a range of values
  const res = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
    spreadsheetId: "16j8hbQHWtg4UUPY5bQOaqOefyY3lFP7tsv1ntMnkKTE",
    range: "A1",

  });


  const cell = res.data.values;
  
  console.log(cell)

  module.exports = cell;
```

My issue arises when I attempt to export the const called 'cell' (which should have the content from a specific cell within my spreadsheet) to the  tag within an HTML file. I tried to use 'import' like so:

```
    <script type="module">
        import cell from "./test.js";
        console.log(cell)

    </script>
```

but this triggers a syntax error: "The requested module 'HTML file' does not provide an export named 'default' "

How do I import the 'const cell' to the HTML script?

Comment: To `import`, you have to do an `export` in `test.js`. But a a few difficulties: (1) generally it's difficult to mix the `require` syntax and the `import/export` es6 syntax. (2) the [googleapis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis) package seems to indicate it's for use in node.js, not browsers...so not sure an import in a `script` tag is going to work. So maybe you need a server side script, and do a fetch or XHR? and (3) even if you can overcome #2, you probably can't import `cell` directly, you'd probably need to import your async function and use return value of promise as cell.

Comment: Exporting a named constant is a named export, so try ‘import { cell } from…’ instead.  Otherwise use ‘export default cell’.